# Returning back to activity after the asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to disable my views and show an alert dialog after returning back from asynctask,i get some result from the background thread, and based on that i have to disable my all views - button, and textview and want to show an alert dialog box!! is it possible??? and how i can approach for this????PLz reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `onPostExecute` method you can do it...And it called after conplition of  `doinBackground(...)`.

`btn.setVisibility(View.GONE)` /// hide any view,view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

and after create AlertDialog also in this method...

Comment: Thank you. It solved my purpose. Can I ask one question? Earlier in m program,I called a method just after invoking my background thread While execution, this method used to be called first then, background thread gets executes. Can you please tell me why this happens??

Answer (score 0):

`onPostExecute` will be run on the main thread and can call a method in your Activity or directly adjust the UI like you normally would in an Activity.

If your `AsyncTask` isn't an inner class of your Activity and doens't have a reference to the Activity object, you could register an intent listener in the Activity which when receiving the correct intent will adjust your UI. Broadcast the intent from your `AsyncTask`